# How can we use a redux form in react table? Also to have need same form for each rows?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have to create a table with different type of fields like text box , drop-down , toggle button etc.

For eg below fields for 20 rows

Name - textbox
Gender - dropdown

I was thinking of creating a redux form and embed it into a table and repeat it for each rows. Also want to bind data per row.

But not sure how to progress with it. Please help and suggest any other way. Due to certain restriction I could not use available components..so I have to create my own component

Comment: go for redux-form and read documents well , its very simple and useful will reduce your maximam work

Comment: Can we add them in a table .. I want each field in a cell?

Comment: yeah why not they are like normal forms with additional functionalities.[follow this](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/examples/fieldarrays/)